# UNIQUE constraint failed: store_order.id

Tags: python, django

i have created a payment system so after successful payment the orders status will change to PAID Here is my models.py :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default="Unpaid")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Here status field has been set to unpaid but when payment is successful it will show PAID

For that i tried this :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=request.session['customer']['id'])
        print(customer)
        user_orders = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['id'])

        # index = Order.objects.get(customer=customer)
        # print(index.total)
        total = user_orders.total
        print(total)
        balance = request.session['customer']['coin']
        print(balance)
        if balance >= total:
            balance = balance - total
            # Customer.objects.filter(id = request.session['customer']['id']).update(coin=balance)
            customer.coin = balance
            customer.save()
            user_orders.status = "PAID"
            user_orders.save()
            request.session['customer']['coin'] = str(balance)

            return HttpResponse("Remaining balance: " + str(balance))

        return HttpResponse("Insufficient Balance")
```

But getting this error : UNIQUE constraint failed: store_order.id

Comment: Seems like what you are trying to do is to add a new record but since both the original "unpaid" order and the new "paid" one have the same order.id sql is refusing since it has been set up with the unique constraint, i.e. the table only accepts unique order ids.

Comment: I didn't see any code involving `store_order`. Are you sure you correctly debugged your code?

Comment: i solved the problem